# Why standard uses exchange in move assignment operator?

Tags: c++

I was experimenting with std::exchange today. According to the cppreference [page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) about std::exchange, this function can be used in both move constructor and move assignment operator. The example from the cppreference is this:

```
struct S
{
  int* p;
  int n;

  S(S&& other)
    :p{std::exchange(other.p, nullptr)}
    ,n{std::exchange(other.n, 0)}
  {}

  S& operator=(S&& other) {
    p = std::exchange(other.p, nullptr); // move p, while leaving nullptr in other.p
    n = std::exchange(other.n, 0); // move n, while leaving zero in other.n
    return *this;
  }
};
```

I don't understand something. The usage of std::exchange in move constructor is OK, because the new (constructed) object will take over the guts of already existing (old) object, and the old object's resource pointer will be assigned nullptr value, so after the move ctor, the old object will be destroyed but the resource will continue to live within the new object.

But in case of the move assignment operator it should work differently, I think. The assignee object should take over the assigned object's resource, and the assigned object should take over the assignee object's resource. After this, when the assigned object is destroyed, it will destroy the resource previously used by the assignee. In other words, the mechanism should swap the resources.
In this code, when the assigned object's resouce pointer will be assigned nullptr then we'll have a leak of resource (the one that used to live in the assignee). Do I understand this correctly? Or am I missing something?

I guess there is something more that I don't know of, since this code is used in the official documentation. Can someone help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: "*the assigned object should take over the assignee object's resource*" Why?

Comment: ^ what he said -- it's entirely unclear where your expectations come from.

Comment: There are two object, A and B. Each of them has a resource allocated. If you assign B to A, then A will take over the resource of B. But what happens to the resource originally allocated by A? It should be assigned to B or deleted immediately in the move assignment operator body. Since the B object will eventually be destroyed soon, it's destructor will be called, so B can take over the A's resource and release it in B's destructor.

Comment: @YotKay, Indeed this example is somehow confusing. Usualy we expected that when a class has pointer member, it should own the pointed object, so it should be responsible to call `delete`. But this is not a necessity, the struct S only observe the pointed to object. This may not be the best example I have seen.

Comment: *"since this code is used in the official documentation"* -- cppreference is not official documentation.

Comment: There's a lesson here: You need to see a class's *destructor* to know what its invariants are. Without knowing what "cleanup" entails, you don't know whether the shown example contains errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there is no "official documentation". cppreference is popular, but it is just a website, and a community-edited one at that. It's certainly not "the standard", and (like any website) it is not unheard of for it to contain bugs … like this one.

Indeed, this is a poor example - not only is the resource not cleaned up properly, it's never even created in the first place.

You can edit the page you're referring to with a better example; it's just a wiki.

Comment: There's no evidence the class in the example is supposed to own any resource, so doesn't need to create it or clean it up. The behaviour in the example is fine for a non-owning class like `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I'm not saying the example is incorrect, just that it is poor. It doesn't seem to demonstrate a class that benefits from moving in any real way. Indeed, `std::reference_wrapper`'s move ctor is deleted.

Comment: Okay, so I _did_ use the term "bug", which is a little strong.

Comment: The [std::exchange](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) example demonstrates a use for std::exchange. The [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Example) and the [move assignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment#Example) examples demonstrate classes that benefit from moving in a real way.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `reference_wrapper` does not have a deleted move ctor, it has a non-existent move ctor, which is not the same as deleted. Its ctor from an rvalue `T` is deleted, but that's to prevent binding references to temporaries, it's not the move ctor.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: That is true. Aside from that nitpick, the end result is still that `std::reference_wrapper` is not semantically moveable, which you well know is the point I was making.

Comment: And the point I was making was that the example shows a non-owning type like `reference_wrapper`, but it's not exactly like `reference_wrapper`. So the move semantics of `reference_wrapper` are not the point. If `reference_wrapper` _did_ have a move constructor that left it empty post-move, it would be defined like the example.